# Can I make a custom emoji through the discord bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I wanna make the emoji with bot.
but i can't find any info about making the emoji.

so my question is "Can i make the emoji through bot?"

Comment: What have you done to figure this out so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.create_custom_emoji

```
with open("my_emoji.jpg", 'rb') as fd:
    await message.guild.create_custom_emoji(name='my_emoji', image=fd.read())
```

Comment: but, What I really want is not image file, the avartar url.

Comment: avatar_bytes = await member.avatar_url.read(); await message.guild.create_custom_emoji(name='my_emoji', image=avatar_bytes)